# SipP "The auto_media_port keyword requires PCAPPLAY."

Tags: centos, centos7, sip, sipp

I have installed Sipp 3.7 on my Centos 7 and whenever I run this command:

```
sipp -i X.X.X.X:5060 -d 600000 -sf videoTEST.xml  -m 200 -rp 1s -s +15555555555 X.X.X.X:5060 -l 4
```

I have the following output:

```
The auto_media_port keyword requires PCAPPLAY.
```

I have checked on the link from [Sipp](https://sipp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) that I need to compile with the following:

```
cmake . -DUSE_PCAP=1
```

I have done that and still the same error.

Things I have to done to try fix it:

-*make pcapplay_ossl* but have this output:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `pcapplay_ossl'.  Stop.
```

-installed wireshark.

-copy sipp file into /usr/bin/sipp

-add -bg -nostdin on the command:

```
sipp -i X.X.X.X:5060 -d 600000 -sf videoTEST.xml  -m 200 -rp 1s -s +15555555555 X.X.X.X:5060 -l 4 -bg -nostdin
```

Does anyone knows what else I'm missing to get rid of this error?

Comment: To anyone facing this issue I follow a script someone made on GitHub. I share with you:
https://github.com/keithcroxford/sipp_installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone facing this issue I follow a script made by keithcroxford on GitHub. I share with you: https://github.com/keithcroxford/sipp_installer

With this I was able to run sipp and not have that issue of pcapplay.

Answer (score 0):

The latest 3.7 sipp doesn't support the [auto_media_port] keyword anymore. See [some information](https://github.com/SIPp/sipp/issues/558) about it. But according to your error message, the sipp build doesn't include the pcap. Check you use correct executable/installation.